# How to create product's custom attribute with 'yes/no' dropdown using install Setup scripts in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I want to Create a product's custom attribute with 'yes/no' drop-down into my custom module.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 15):

Step-1: Create a InstallData.php file with below script

VendorName/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
* Init
*
* @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
*/
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            /**
            * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
            */

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'custom_attribute',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'Custom Label',
                    'input' => 'boolean',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Rajesh, I am getting Class doesn't error

Answer (score 7):

You can create custom attribute using Upgrade script also:
Create file below path:

**namespace Custom\Product\Setup\UpgradeData.php**

```
<?php  
namespace Custom\Product\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.1.51') < 0)
        {
            
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                 \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute_name', [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Custom Attribute Name',
                'input' => 'select',
                'group' => 'General',
                'class' => 'custom_attribute_name',
                'source' => 'Boolean',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '1',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false
                    ]
            );
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
        ?>
```

I hope,this will help you.

Comment: Yes/No already exists in Magento core, there is no need to create a new source.

Comment: Edited the answer, check \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean