# Magento2 Ui Component - How to create dynamic rows attribute like custom options on the product form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, ecommerce-tracking

kindly give me a solution / advice for how to achieve this following concept in magento 2.

I want to implement this concept on the product edit form at admin side, also i want to fetch and get updated saved values.

Concept:
I need to setup / create new attribute like custom option, for ex:

**Lable**: `Delivery information`

**Field in row**: `Destination and Days to deliver`

**Field 1** : `Destination (Select type)`

**Field 2**: `Days to deliver (Text box, validate Integer Only)`

**Add Value** : `Used to create new row to select and enter different values`

As Image, Should be like this

[image]

Based on these information i need to filer those products by destination and delivery day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204998/how-to-create-products-custom-attribute-with-yes-no-dropdown-using-install-se

Comment: @Msquare this is not matching with my concept. thanks for your suggestion.!

Comment: @ManiMaranA Would like to do something similar did you get a solution for this?